# Magento Bundles: Options' displayed price calculated from default choice price, not from zero

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

The product myBundle has myColorOption with these items:

- Green $50
- Blue $100
- Red $100
- Black $150

Magento 1.4.2.0 per default will present the customer with a select dropdown with options like this:

- Green +$50
- Blue +$100
- Red +$100
- Black +$150

The change I am looking for is when a default item has been selected by admin. When it is, each displayed price should be relative to that of the default option. If admin sets Blue (price $100) as the default item for the option, the dropdown should now read:

- Green -$50
- Blue
- Red
- Black +$50

To clarify: I only want the displayed price in the dropdown to change, the actual price added to cart and used for other calculations remains the same.

---

**Update:** Here's the code I have so far, the problem is in the commented lines. I need help getting the correct models etc.

```
<?php
// From file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php
// copied to app/code/local/Mage/...
public function getSelectionTitlePrice($_selection, $includeContainer = true)
{
    $defaultPrice = 0.00;
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    /*
    $_mbmo = new Mage_Bundle_Model_Option();
    $_mbmo->load($_selection->getProductId());
    $_default = $_mbmo->getDefaultSelection();
    $defaultPrice = $_product->getPriceModel()->getSelectionPreFinalPrice($_product, $_default, 1);
    */
    $price = $_product->getPriceModel()->getSelectionPreFinalPrice($_product, $_selection, 1);
    if ($price == $defaultPrice)
    {
        return $_selection->getName();
    }
    else
    {
        $sign = ($price < $defaultPrice) ?  '-' : '+';
        $diff = ($price < $defaultPrice) ? $defaultPrice - $price : $price - $defaultPrice;
        return $_selection->getName() . ' &nbsp; ' .
            ($includeContainer ? '<span class="price-notice">':'') . $sign .
            $this->formatPriceString($diff, $includeContainer) . ($includeContainer ? '</span>':'');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
$defaultPrice = $_product->getPriceModel()->getSelectionPreFinalPrice($_product, $_default,1);
```

Replace above line with below

```
$defaultPrice=$this->getOption()->getDefaultSelection()->getSelectionPriceValue();
```

Comment: For some reason ->getSelectionPriceValue() returns 0.000 every time, but ->getPrice() works fine! Thank you SO much for answering, really appreciated!

Comment: Hi for some reason this is not working correctly for me. I have added the code, but it keeps showing the same prices Ie Green $50 Blue $100 Red $100 Black $150 what am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to add something to this answer - I was finding that the code would fail if it tried to call getDefaultSelection()->getPrice() against an option that had no default value.  Was able to fix this by adding the following code:

```
$_mbmo = new Mage_Bundle_Model_Option();
$_mbmo->load($_selection->getProductId());
$_default = $_mbmo->getDefaultSelection();

if (gettype($this->getOption()->getDefaultSelection())==object){
$defaultPrice=$this->getOption()->getDefaultSelection()->getPrice();
}
```

Basically just does a check that something is returned from calling getDefaultSelection() on $this and then proceeds with setting default price, otherwise it just carries on with the rest of the code.